# Can I have two different input fields and one column in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have two input fields, but only one column in the database.
The first input is stored data in numbers and the other one is stored data in numbers divided by 24.
You can put data only in one field.
Is there any possible way to do this?

UPD:
Migration:

```rb
def change
  add_column :employees, :hourly_payment , :integer
end
```

View:
employees/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @employee do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.input :hourly_payment %>
  <%= form.input :monthly_payment %>
  <%= form.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: *Yes.* There is nothing exception convention that links an input on the front end to a database column. There are tons of ways of doing this like using a custom setter or transforming the parameter in the controller. Your models/tables are really an internal implementation detail and can and will deviate from the public API that you're exposing to the client.

Comment: The question is extremely confusingly worded though. Is this some sort of interview question or a real world problem? What do you expect as user input and what is it that you're actually going to store? Please give an example.

Comment: I reread my question and it is confusing.
For example, I want to have two fields for salary for an employee. 
The first field accepts hourly payment and the other one accepts monthly salary that I will divide by 168. Users can input data only in one field.

Comment: There are some huge problems with that unless you're going a very rough estimate of the hourly wage - months have varying numbers of days and it will be very missleading for part time jobs.

Comment: A better solution is most likely to store the salary and the type of contract - or even better  use a separate table for this so that you can keep records of the varying wages. You can't normalize a monthly wage into hours - they are actually completely different entities.

Comment: It is just an example, not a real case.

Comment: @max but I like your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model and database tables are the internals of your application and are not actually tied to the view by anything except how easy ActiveRecord makes it to use convention over configuration to link the two*.

In Rails style MVC the controller is responsible for passing user input to the model. Usually you would just do this with simple mass assignment:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    # ...
  end

  private 

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:email, :salary)
  end
end
```

This is basically just passing a whitelisted hash of parameters straight to the model as is and it all gets passed to the setters that ActiveRecord magically created for you by reading the database schema.

But there is nothing stopping you from assigning attributes manually:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) do |user|
      user.salary = calculated_salary
    end
    # ...
  end

  private 

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:email)
  end

  def calculated_salary
     if params[:user][:hourly_payment].present?
       params[:user][:hourly_payment]
     elsif params[:user][:monthly_payment].present?
       params[:user][:monthly_payment].to_i / 168
     else
        0 # sorry no cookies for you
     end
  end
end
```

Or monkeying with the parameters object:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
        .permit(:email)
        .merge(salary: calculated_salary)
end
```

It is after all just a hash on steroids. The only thing that Rails will prevent you from is passing a parameters object that has not been whitelisted.

There is no stone tablet for what you can do in a controller. The only thing to bear in mind is that controllers are notoriously hard to test and fat controllers are a recipe for disaster.

If you're doing anything more complicated there are better solutions such as [form objects](https://jaryl.medium.com/disciplined-rails-form-object-techniques-patterns-part-1-23cfffcaf429), decorators or service objects.

Comment: * how easy it is to strongly link the two is both the biggest strength and weakness of ActiveRecord. You can get going extremely fast but it doesn't encourage you to actually seperate the concerns properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a view for that. Here is an example of migration:

```rb
def up
  sql = %(CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view_models AS
  SELECT m.*,m.int_field*12 as my_new_value from my_models m
  )
  self.connection.execute(sql)
end

def down
  self.connection.execute('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_view_models')
end
```

Then, you can access your value with method `my_new_value` on your model. You'll need to change the name of the default table matching your model.

```rb
class MyModel
  self.table_name = 'my_view_models'
end
```

And access it via

```
MyModel.first.my_new_value
```